# How to set states for a specific index in an array map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which has a text area for building name and a delete icon.The text comes from the value entered in a text box.So, the user can add more than one building. The page looks like this:

[image: building]

So, when we click on add another building, we will be redirected to the previous page where we can enter the building names.Then the new building will be added to the array of buildings and it looks like this.
[image: building2]

So, my code for displaying both the pages for entering the building Name and the list of building names entered is as shown below:

```
{
            (this.state.addBuildingFirstPage && !this.state.closeBuildingHeader) ?
              <BuildingContent
                buildingNames={this.state.buildingNames}
                onClickAddBuildingButtonHandler={this.onClickAddBuildingButtonHandler}
                onClickShowBuildingListHandler={this.onClickShowBuildingListHandler}
                onClickAddBuildingTextBoxHandler={this.onClickAddBuildingTextBoxHandler}
                navigateToDashboardHandler={this.props.navigateToDashboardHandler}
                getBuildingRadioButtonValueHandler={this.props.getBuildingRadioButtonValueHandler}
                hideAddBuildingImageHandler={this.hideAddBuildingImageHandler} 
                openBuildingNameComponentHandler={this.openBuildingNameComponentHandler} />
              :

              (this.state.openBuildingNameComponent ?
                <BuildingName

                  deleteBuildingFlag={this.state.deleteBuildingFlag}
                  buildingNames={this.state.buildingNames}
                  onClickDeleteBuildingIconHandler={this.onClickDeleteBuildingIconHandler}
                  onClickAddAnotherBuildingButtonHandler={this.onClickAddAnotherBuildingButtonHandler}
                  navigateToAddressPageHandler={this.props.navigateToAddressPageHandler}
                  navigateToDashboardHandler={this.props.navigateToDashboardHandler}
                  navigateToAddPropertHandler={this.props.navigateToAddPropertHandler} />
                : null)
          }
```

So `<BuildingContent />` component is the one where we enter the building name in the text box. And `<BuildingName />` component is the one where the list of buildings is shown, i.e. the component for the screenshot attached.

**Currently my issue is in deleting a particular building.**

So, for now what I have done is, I have written a callback function :

```
onClickDeleteBuildingIconHandler = () => {
    this.setState({ deleteBuildingFlag: true });
  }
```

and passed it to `<BuildingName />` component as props.

And my `<BuildingName />` component looks as shown below:

```
{!this.props.deleteBuildingFlag ?
          (this.props.buildingNames.map((building, i) => {
            return (
              <div className={classes.sceFullWd} key={'building' + i}>
                <div className={classes.sceBuildingNameContainer}>
                  <div className={classes.sceBenchmarkingBuildingName}>
                    {building}
                  </div>
                  <button
                    className={classes.sceCloseIcon}
                    onClick={this.props.onClickDeleteBuildingIconHandler}>
                    <i className={"fas fa-times " + classes.sceBuildingCloseIcon} />
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          }))
          : null}
```

But I am not able to understand how to set the state for the specific deletion of the building.So, how do I proceed?

Comment: Why can't you just remove building from array? Another option is to add `isDeleted` field for building object and write `onClick` function that receive this object and sets flag.

Comment: @Dracontis The issue is in setting the delete flag for each index of the array.Currently we have a delete flag, but on click of it, the complete array of buildings gets deleted

Comment: Posted an answer that shows what I mean in my first comment. Because  it require some coding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target a specific entry in the list, I recommend using the key you generated in the map. So I propose a change to this:

```
// entry will be the key of the list
onClickDeleteBuildingIconHandler = entry => {
    this.setState({ deleteBuilding: entry });
  }
```

and in the component:

```
{this.props.buildingNames.map((building, i) => {
  if (this.props.deleteBuildingFlag == i) {
    return null;
    }
            return (
              <div className={classes.sceFullWd} key={'building' + i}>
                <div className={classes.sceBuildingNameContainer}>
                  <div className={classes.sceBenchmarkingBuildingName}>
                    {building}
                  </div>
                  <button
                    className={classes.sceCloseIcon}
                    //use the key here 
                    onClick={() => this.props.onClickDeleteBuildingIconHandler(i)}>
                    <i className={"fas fa-times " + classes.sceBuildingCloseIcon} />
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })
```

Comment: I tried using the way you suggested.But,I am getting an error while setting the state.Because my state value is initalized boolean.So how to do that?

Comment: You could initialize your state with null. I also edited the check in the component.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't or don't want to remove building `onDelete` event then you should manipulate with array of objects with `name` and `isDelete` flag:

```
this.props.buildingObjects.map((building, i) => {
  if (building.isDeleted) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.sceFullWd} key={'building' + i}>
      <div className={classes.sceBuildingNameContainer}>
        <div className={classes.sceBenchmarkingBuildingName}>
          {building.name}
        </div>
        <button
          className={classes.sceCloseIcon}
          onClick={this.props.onClickDeleteBuildingIconHandler(building)}>
            <i className={"fas fa-times " + classes.sceBuildingCloseIcon} />
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
})
```

And `onClick` event should look like this:

```
onClickDeleteBuildingIconHandler = (buildingObj) => {
  return () => {
    buildingObj.isDeleted = true;
    // Also you'll need call setState to rerender buildings
    this.setState({ deleteBuildingFlag: !this.state.deleteBuildingFlag });
  }
}
```

Or you could avoid objects and path index to the function and just remove index from the array. But it is depends on implementation and your desires.

Comment: But my array is a list of the buildingNames, it doesn't contain any other parameters.So , i sit not possible to implement the same with only the names?

Comment: @pranami In programming nothing is impossible! You could create array of deleted building names and instead of  `if (building.isDeleted)` use `if (deletedBuildingsArray.includes(building))`. But it's pornography and black magic, and also it will exclude all buildings with the same name.